# UPDATE só dos campos que estão com mais de 0 caracteres

Tags: php, mysql

Oi, estou com uma tabela com vários inputs e preciso que faça o UPDATE dos campos com mais de 0 caracteres, os que tiverem com 0 ou em branco ficam do jeito que esta! Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso ?

segue meu código:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE `is` SET `janmembros` = '$janmembros', `janvisitantes` = '$janvisitantes', `fevmembros` = '$fevmembros', `fevvisitantes` = '$fevvisitantes',  `marmembros` = '$marmembros', `marvisitantes` = '$marvisitantes', `abrmembros` = '$abrmembros', `abrvisitantes` = '$abrvisitantes', `maimembros` = '$maimembros', `maivisitantes` = '$maivisitantes', `julmembros` = '$julmembros', `julvisitantes` = '$julvisitantes', `junmembros` = '$junmembros', `junvisitantes` = '$junvisitantes', `agomembros` = '$agomembros', `agovisitantes` = '$agovisitantes', `setmembros` = '$setmembros', `setvisitantes` = '$setvisitantes', `outvisitantes` = '$outvisitantes', `outmembros` = '$outmembros', `novmembros` = '$novmembros', `outvisitantes` = '$outvisitantes', `novmembros` = '$novmembros', `novvisitantes` = '$novvisitantes', `dezmembros` = '$dezmembros', `dezvisitantes` = '$dezvisitantes' WHERE `celula` LIKE '$celula'") or die(mysql_error());
```

por serem muitos campos para atualizar fica muito dificil de fazer com IF, exemplo:

```
if (strlen($janmembros) > 0)
{
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `is` SET `janmembros` = '$janmembros' WHERE `celula` LIKE '$celula'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que dá é pra simplificar um pouco o código, organizando os IFs:

```
<?php

   $sets = '';
   $sets .= strlen( $janmembros    ) > 0 ? "SET janvisitantes = '".$janmembros   ."'";
   $sets .= strlen( $janvisitantes ) > 0 ? "SET janmembros    = '".$janvisitantes."'";
   $sets .= strlen( $fevmembros    ) > 0 ? "SET fevmembros    = '".$fevmembros   ."'";
   ... outros sets ...

   mysql_query( "UPDATE `is` ".$sets." WHERE `celula` LIKE '$celula'") or die(mysql_error())

?>
```

Notar que seu código tem no mínimo dois problemas sérios:

- Um é a possibilidade de SQL Injection, que pode ser resolvida com essa sintaxe:

  ```
  $sets.=strlen($janmembros)>0?"SET janvisitantes='".mysql_real_escape_string($janmembros)."'";
  ```

  (em todas as linhas do set, e no `WHERE`).
- Você deveria usar `mysqli` no lugar da lib `mysql`, que está obsoleta.

Além disso, talvez seja o caso de revisar a estrutura do seu DB em vez de colocar muita informação na mesma linha da tabela.

<sub>Poderia ser feita uma função, com um *array* contendo os nomes dos campos, que gerasse a query para você, mas é o típico esforço numa coisa que não justifica o trabalho, e que atrapalha mais o entendimento e aumenta a complexidade. Melhor dar *copy* e *paste* em uma duzia de linhas e conseguir enxergar o que está acontecendo.</sub>

Comment: valew @Bacco, não testei ainda mas acho que é isso q eu precisava!!!